# Optimal way to calculate the % of a file transferred

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

This is simple in concept, but just seems like too much work for a minimal task:

I have a file that is being uploaded, and want to output, to the user, the % that has been uploaded. This is the basic working code below.

(Note: _fileLength is of float type and is previously checked that it is not 0 when set. _lastPercent is of int type):

```
UpdateProgress(long written)
{  
  int percent = -1;

  float f = written / _fileLength;
  percent = (int)(100 * f);

  if(-1 != percent && percent != _lastPercent)
  {
    _lastPercent = percent;
    UpdateProgressUI(percent);
  }
}
```

This code works just fine, but it seems overzealous to call this method with each packet sent. I've fooled around with timers as well, where the % is only checked/updated on a timed-increment, but that showed negligible performance increase. Am I stuck with this? Is there a nicer way to do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not obvious why you fret over code that takes at most a handful of nanoseconds and can never update the UI more than a 100 times.  Just measure more with Stopwatch, best way to get a feel for how much code actually costs.

Comment: @HansPassant Yeah, you're right honestly....I love stopwatch bench-marking and I'm surprised I've overlooked that step in my process. I has a feeling that optimizing this may have been pointless/negligible, so your response is appreciated in that confirmation at least. I'll benchmark this and see how much of a time hog this method really is, I'll update if the benchmark time seems to be an issue. Thanks.